# Run code when a cell changes. Unable to watch more than one cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to watch 2 cells in my worksheet to see if a user changes them. If they do then I want it to run code depending on which one was changed. I get no errors, but it ignores one of the cells. Is this only capable of watching one cell?

Currently I am using an "ElseIF" to check the other cell, I have also tried using a "," to place both in the first part of the if statement, (which crashed excel)

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A5, "E4")) Is Nothing Then
```

and I tried using a "Or" in the first part of the If statement

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A5")) Is Nothing Or Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("E4")) Is Nothing Then
```

( which did nothing)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A5")) Is Nothing Then

If [A5] = "Day Shift:" Then

    ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect "Welcome1"

    Worksheets("5001 Prog").Unprotect "Welcome1"

        Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("25:120").EntireRow.Hidden = False

        Sheets("5001 HDD Days").Visible = True
        Sheets("5001 HDD Nights").Visible = False

        Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("B5").Value = Worksheets("Variables").Range("E10").Value

        Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("B4").Value = Worksheets("Variables").Range("M10").Value

        Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("73:120").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    ActiveWorkbook.Protect "Welcome1"

Else

    ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect "Welcome1"

    Worksheets("5001 Prog").Unprotect "Welcome1"

        Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("25:120").EntireRow.Hidden = False

        Sheets("5001 HDD Days").Visible = False
        Sheets("5001 HDD Nights").Visible = True

        Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("B5").Value = Worksheets("Variables").Range("E11").Value

        Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("B4").Value = Worksheets("Variables").Range("M11").Value

         Worksheets("5001 Prog").Range("25:72").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Worksheets("5001 Prog").Protect "Welcome1"

    ActiveWorkbook.Protect "Welcome1"
End If

'Updates the last ream pass with the current foreman
    Call Update_Totals

'Selects the "5001 Prog" page
    Worksheets("5001 Prog").Select

ElseIf Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("E4")) Is Nothing Then

'Updates the last ream pass with the current foreman
    Call Update_Totals

'Selects the "5001 Prog" page
    Worksheets("5001 Prog").Select

ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("E4")) Is Nothing Then

'Updates the last ream pass with the current foreman
    Call Update_Totals

'Selects the "5001 Prog" page
    Worksheets("5001 Prog").Select


Else
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You should try it like this... If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A5,E4")) Is Nothing Then

Comment: That Worked!!! Thank you! I guess having them in one set of quotations is important? Or is it the "If Not Intersect(Target, Range" part?

Comment: `Range("A5, "E4")` refers to A4,A5,B4,B5,C4,C5,D4,D5,E4,E5; in other words, those two cells and everything in between. Same as `Range("A5:E4")`. `Range("A5,E4")` refers to A5 and E4 only.

Comment: @Jeeped Actually `Range("A5, "E4")` would give a syntax error, which is why Prettify got confused with it in the OP's question.  ;)

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K - I had missed the missing double quote and read it as `Range("A5", "E4")`

Comment: @Jeeped Based on the OP's comments, I assume the `Range("A5", "E4")` must be what the OP **really** tried, but I was about to make a comment pointing out the syntax error to them when I saw the other comments and couldn't resist having a dig at you for having repeated the issue in your comment. :D

Comment: @YowE3K - But he (if I can assume that Thomas the plane is a male) stated *'I want to watch 2 cells in my worksheet'* which would indicate the union of `Range("A5, E4")`. If that was contradicted in comments then I guess he really doesn't know what he actually wants. I was just trying to clarify *'I guess having them in one set of quotations is important?'*.

Comment: @Jeeped Yes, the OP is definitely after `Range("A5,E4")` and not the `Range("A5", "E4")` that they tried.  FWIW, I was thinking they **might** have tried `Range("A5, "E4")` and their comment "(which crashed excel)" may have simply referred to the syntax error (although it was a bit of a stretch to call a compile error a "crash"), but if they had used the `Range("A5", "E4")` it would have started invoking the `Change` event recursively due to the updates to cells B4 and B5 and that would **definitely** crash Excel - so the missing `"` seems to just be a posting issue.

Comment: @Thomastheplane You're welcome! Glad it worked. The double quotes were the issue, you used them in wrong way. Go through the discussions above and you will have an idea about it. :)

Comment: Thank you all very much. It was indeed a posting error. I meant to put 'Range("A5", "E4")' not 'Range("A5, "E4")' .  When I used  'Range("A5", "E4")'  Excel would freeze then Microsoft would try to recover and end up closing the software.